# How do I interrupt a loop in a command-line script, but only after the method finishes?

Tags: ruby

I have a Ruby script that looks like:

```
def big_function
  puts "starting..."
  #does stuff
  puts "done"
end

loop do
  big_function
end
```

It runs indefinitely, executing `big_function`.

I need a way for a user to interrupt the running script but never in the middle of `big_function`. If it is interrupted while `big_function` is running, it should exit when `big_function` is done.

Comment: Just instruct them to press Ctrl+C

Comment: won't it exit before the function is done?

Comment: Yes, it will. Maybe interrupting the script is not what you want. Who is going to use this script (save or novice users)?

Comment: not enough information - what does big_function do? does it wait for the user's input, which interface is given to the user(GUI, command line)...

Comment: I've added the complete version of the code

Comment: @Sergey it processes database entries, takes around a minute each. It's a command line script. mabounassif's solution worked well

Comment: Traditionally, this is done by trapping interrupts. Inside the trap, you set a flag then continue. Outside the trap, in your loop, you look for that flag to see if it has been set. If so, you exit. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/3966624/128421 for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use flags. You can have a separate process polling in the key triggering of the user, and if he clicks or press a key that flag changes state. You will have to check the flag before exiting.

```
flag = false

t = Thread.new() {
  loop do
    flag = gets
    break if flag
  end
}

def big_function
  puts "starting..."
  #does stuff
  puts "done"
end

loop do
  break if flag
  big_function
end
```

Answer (score 4):

[Trap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-trap) does that:

```
interrupted = false
trap("INT") { interrupted = true } # traps Ctrl-C
puts 'Press Ctrl-C to exit'

def big_function
  puts "starting..."
  sleep 1
  puts "done"
end

until interrupted do
  big_function
end
```